# Colocar imagem em <input> em html e css

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber como é possível colocar uma imagem PNG dentro de um `<input>` à esquerda, algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código é bastante extenso por isso um trecho:

CSS:

```
#span1{
    
    background:url(../images/Sample_User_Icon.png);
    padding-left:30px;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div >
     <input id=input1 type="text" placeholder="Insert Username *" style="position: absolute; 
      top: 90px; left: 20px;">
     <span id=span1></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer em *CSS* usando as propriedades de estilo de fundo para colocar um avatar dentro do input. As propriedades são:

- [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image): A propriedade define uma ou mais imagens de fundo em um elemento. Aqui será usada a imagem dum [avatar anônimo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VED3b.jpg).
- [`background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat): A propriedade define como as imagens de fundo são repetidas. Nesse caso `no-repeat` sem repetições.
- [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/background-position): A propriedade define a posição inicial para cada imagem de fundo. No caso `left`, estará posicionada a esquerda.
- [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/background-size): A propriedade define o tamanho da imagem de fundo do elemento. Aqui `1.3em`. Veja [Valores e unidades CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units).

Também use a propriedade [`padding-left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/padding-left) para definir um espaço entre o conteúdo do elemento e sua borda esquerda.

```css
#usr {    
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/eKw2dvH.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  background-size: 1.3em;
  padding-left: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="usr" placeholder="Insert Username *">
```

O mesmo objetivo também pode ser alcançado utilizado a propriedade atalho [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/background) define todas as propriedades de estilo de fundo de uma só vez.

```css
#usr {
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/eKw2dvH.png") no-repeat left / 1.3em;
  padding-left: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="usr" placeholder="Insert Username *">
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso vc precisa de uma estrutura como esta:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><img src="link-to-image"></span>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

O código que estiliza isso precisaria fazer o seguinte: Remover o estilo do input (borda principalmente), a div .input-group precisa nesse caso ter o estilo do input (borda, hover etc), um bom exemplo de estilo disso é o input group do bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/)